# What is this thing in the picture called in English?

Tags: terminology, image-identification, lexicon

What is that thing that opens usually on top of the window called?

[image: That thing that opens usually on top of the window]

Comment: Do you mean the *latch*?

Comment: More description needed. Do you mean the whole thing that swings open? Or the handle/lock that can be used to open/close the whole-thing-that-swings-open?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen one before. Can you perhaps describe its function etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "top"? Do you mean "on" or "high up"? Please *circle* in red or use an arrow to show ***exactly*** what you are referring to. Is it the window frame, the latch/handle, the glass that opens. It's really too vague/unclear.

Comment: If this is what I think it is, it's a small window inset into a larger window, commonly found in older Russian apartment buildings which are heated by central steam plants (ie, no individual thermostats).  The small window is opened in the winter to provide some fresh air if the room is too hot.  I don't think there's a particular word for that in English...

Answer (score 6):

***Transom***.  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transom) says:

> 1 : **a window above a door or other window built on and commonly
>   hinged  to a transom**
>
> 2 : a transverse piece in a structure : crosspiece: such as,  a :
>   lintel;  b : a horizontal crossbar in a window, over a door, or
>   between a door  and a window or fanlight above it
>
> 2d. any of several transverse timbers or beams secured to the sternpost
>   of a boat; also : the planking forming the stern of a square-ended
>   boat  (emphasis added)

That is, transom originally meant a horizontal crossbar, and then the window above a door or window was called a transom.  I remember that all the doors in my primary school had transoms, for ventilation, because the doors were shut for classes, the windows were rarely opened, and air-conditioning was rare in those far-off days.

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/204957?redirectedFrom=transom#eid) (OED) says of Definition 1 (which I took from  Merriam-Webster) that it is US Colloquial and the first quotation the OED gives is from 1844.  The OED has a quotation from 1487 for the definition 2a and 2b sense, and a quotation from 1545 for the naval use of transom. Unfortunately, the OED is behind a pay-wall and the multiple definitions of, and quotations for, transom are too long to copy here.

Comment: The key word in the first definition is "commonly"; if it had said "always," the window in the OP's photo wouldn't qualify as a transom because it is hinged to a continuation of one of the vertical pieces of the door (or whatever it is) beneath, rather than to the crosspiece (transom proper) above the door. But given the "commonly hinged" wording, I think this answer is correct. Its crucial advantage over "top light" or "fan light" is that it is normally hinged to permit opening, whereas a top light/fan light may not be (as we see in the photo near the bottom of Nigel J's answer.

Answer (score 4):

**I am assuming that the question is about the type of window :**

An opening window above another fixed window is called a **top light** or **fan light** window. [See diagram]. 'Fanlight', strictly speaking, is a window in the shape of a fan but since they were always in the 'top light' position, usually above a door, the term 'fan light' has extended to mean any top light window.

Image taken from [Arden Windows](http://www.ardenwindows.net/window-terms).

See image 1 for 'top light' or 'fan light'.

[image]

Example of Fan Light Window taken from [Old English Doors](http://www.oldenglishdoors.co.uk/bespoke/fanlights/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a *window latch / lock*?

Comment: It's not actually clear what part of the photograph the question is asking about. We're usually looking for answers that explain why they're right, rather than just providing a word to use. In this case, if you'd said something like "The catch metal part that keeps the window closed is...", it would be clearer which part you meant. (For example, the hand might be pointing to the whole opening pane.)

Comment: yes, it got me puzzled as well. I thought simply googling the given word would clarify it enough for the asker. I'll keep it in mind, thanks.

Comment: Yeah. We prefer answers to be reasonably self-contained. Googling for extra information is fine, but having to Google to find out even what an answer means is a bit much. But thanks for contributing! Hopefully, there are some clearer questions you can help out on. :-)

Comment: @ashala2202 use comment section, if you have doubts.